# Connect to IMAP Alfresco with Outlook 2013 without caching

Tags: caching, outlook, imap, alfresco, outlook-2013

I configured IMAP in Alfresco and connected with Outlook 2013. The problem is that Alfresco will contain multiple GBs of emails and Outlook seems to cache all emails on local storage. This is not acceptable. In settings i can only set the amount of cached emails to last 1, 2, 4, ... months or all emails. Has anybody experienced this problem? Thanks for help!

edit: looks like this is not possible anymore in Outlook 2013 http://www.msoutlook.info/question/412

Answer (score 1):

IMAP4 stores (unlike Exchange) are always cached in Outlook.